# NetApi32 for UNC path is returning error code 1326

Tags: c#, iis

I have been trying to drop a file into a samba share folder within my application for the past few days.

**Story so far**

I took a copy of the `UNCAccessWithCredentials` class found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43091/Connect-to-a-UNC-Path-with-Credentials) and referenced it in my repository. This class uses the `NetApi32.dll`

I wrote the following code to check whether a connection was present, and if there was not one, to create the connection.

```
bool available = UNCConnection.IsNetworkPathAvailable(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"ExportFilePath"]);

        string uncpath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"ExportFilePath"];
        string user = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportUser"];
        string password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportPassword"];
        string domain = @"";
        string filePath = uncpath + @"\exportFile" + ".txt";

        if (!available)
        {
            using (UNCAccessWithCredentials unc = new UNCAccessWithCredentials())
            {

                var x = unc.NetUseWithCredentials(uncpath, user, domain, password);

                if (x)
                {
                    CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
                    cc.Write(
                    chargesForExport,
                    filePath,
                    outputFileDescription);
                }
                else
                {
                    var error = unc.GetStatusCodeDefinition(unc.LastError);
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("The following error occured whilst writing to the creditors folder: {0}", error));
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
            cc.Write(
            chargesForExport,
            filePath,
            outputFileDescription);
        }
```

**The problem**

When running this in debug via IIS Express, this works no problem.
I have run 'net use' from the cmd line and set a breakpoint on `unc.NetUseWithCredentials`

Before - No connection

During - Connection

After Using - No Connection

When I deploy to live, or host locally on full blown IIS I see error code **'1326'** which I believe means `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE`. These credentials defiantly work because I can use them to browse to the folder, and I can use them to map a network drive to this folder and they are the same credentials I am using when it works in debug.

**What I have tried**

I have tried mapping a network share, closing any existing connections using netuse /delete, changing the identity in the IIS app pool to a custom account neither the administrator or my personal AD account made a difference. I have also ran caspol to set the policy to full trust but I still see error **1326**.

I don't understand why this works perfectly when running off IIS Express, but the minute I host this on full blown IIS, I only see error **1326**.

Can anyone see the problem here!?

**UNCAccessWithCredentials Class**

```
 public class UNCAccessWithCredentials : IDisposable
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct USE_INFO_2
        {
            internal LPWSTR ui2_local;
            internal LPWSTR ui2_remote;
            internal LPWSTR ui2_password;
            internal DWORD ui2_status;
            internal DWORD ui2_asg_type;
            internal DWORD ui2_refcount;
            internal DWORD ui2_usecount;
            internal LPWSTR ui2_username;
            internal LPWSTR ui2_domainname;
        }

        [DllImport("NetApi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern NET_API_STATUS NetUseAdd(
            LPWSTR UncServerName,
            DWORD Level,
            ref USE_INFO_2 Buf,
            out DWORD ParmError);

        [DllImport("NetApi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern NET_API_STATUS NetUseDel(
            LPWSTR UncServerName,
            LPWSTR UseName,
            DWORD ForceCond);

        private bool disposed = false;

        private string sUNCPath;
        private string sUser;
        private string sPassword;
        private string sDomain;
        private int iLastError;

        /// <summary>
        /// A disposeable class that allows access to a UNC resource with credentials.
        /// </summary>
        public UNCAccessWithCredentials()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The last system error code returned from NetUseAdd or NetUseDel.  Success = 0
        /// </summary>
        public int LastError
        {
            get { return iLastError; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                NetUseDelete();
            }
            disposed = true;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Connects to a UNC path using the credentials supplied.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="UNCPath">Fully qualified domain name UNC path</param>
        /// <param name="User">A user with sufficient rights to access the path.</param>
        /// <param name="Domain">Domain of User.</param>
        /// <param name="Password">Password of User</param>
        /// <returns>True if mapping succeeds.  Use LastError to get the system error code.</returns>
        public bool NetUseWithCredentials(string UNCPath, string User, string Domain, string Password)
        {
            sUNCPath = UNCPath;
            sUser = User;
            sPassword = Password;
            sDomain = Domain;
            return NetUseWithCredentials();
        }

        private bool NetUseWithCredentials()
        {
            uint returncode;
            try
            {
                USE_INFO_2 useinfo = new USE_INFO_2();

                useinfo.ui2_remote = sUNCPath;
                useinfo.ui2_username = sUser;
                useinfo.ui2_domainname = sDomain;
                useinfo.ui2_password = sPassword;
                useinfo.ui2_asg_type = 0;
                useinfo.ui2_usecount = 1;
                uint paramErrorIndex;
                returncode = NetUseAdd(null, 2, ref useinfo, out paramErrorIndex);
                iLastError = (int)returncode;
                return returncode == 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                iLastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ends the connection to the remote resource 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True if it succeeds.  Use LastError to get the system error code</returns>
        public bool NetUseDelete()
        {
            uint returncode;
            try
            {
                returncode = NetUseDel(null, sUNCPath, 2);
                iLastError = (int)returncode;
                return (returncode == 0);
            }
            catch
            {
                iLastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                return false;
            }
        }

        ~UNCAccessWithCredentials()
        {
            Dispose();
        }


        public string GetStatusCodeDefinition(int errorCode)
        {
           var test = (StatusCodeDefinitions)errorCode;

            return test.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code that does the connection? It's not available directly from the linked website without registration. - Otherwise the first I'd do is tracing the configuration settings. Have you made sure that the IIS Express deployment and the full IIS deployment use the same values for ExportUser and ExportPassword?

Comment: Yes the config values are the same, I have checked and double checked this.